# Laravel/Passport doesn't redirect back to authorization form after login

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Here is how I handle the login in my Laravel app:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => hash('sha512', $request->password)
        );

        if (User::where($credentials)->exists()) {
            $user = User::where($credentials)->first();
            Auth::login($user, isset($request->remember));
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login', ['error' => $validator->errors()->first()]);
    }
}
```

And here is how I initiate the Authorize method of Laravel Passport:

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put('state', $state = Str::random(40));

    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => '3',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/authorize/response',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
        'state' => $state
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
}
```

So basically when I run `auth` function and I am not logged in when I nabvigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize....` url I get redirected to the Login route of my app. That's fine I need to login to authorize the permission. So far so good.

The problem is that after I login successfully I don't get redirected back to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize...` URL. Why?

How can I fix that so that after I login I get directly redirected back to the Authorization prompt?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this. I've upgraded to Passport 11 and encountering the same issue. This was all working in version 10

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when I was authorizing clients with PKCE. I am not sure if it's the most elegant way to achieve that but it works anyways.

In order to solve this issue I created a middleware named `KeepClientParameters` and stored client request in session.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class KeepClientParameters
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ('code' === $request->get('response_type', false)) {
            $allParams = $request->all();
            $request->session()->put('client', $allParams);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And set middleware priority in App/Http/Kernel.php, below `StartSession::class` and above `AuthenticatesRequests::class` because you should run the middleware before authentication requests, otherwise you will not be able to store your client request in session.

```php
    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * Forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [        
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

        
        \App\Http\Middleware\KeepClientParameters::class,

        // ...
       
        \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticatesRequests::class,
    ];
```

After successful Authentication, you can redirect to Authorization page and pull session data in authorization page.

```php
$client = $request->session()->pull('client', []);
return redirect(
      route('passport.authorizations.authorize', $client)
);
```